# SGPLOT Two Y Axes

Tags: sas

I have a dataset that looks like the following:

```
  pt_fin    Admit_Type    MONTH_YEAR   BED_ORDERED_TO_DISPO (minutes)
     1        Acute             Jan              214
     2        Acute             Jan              628
     3        ICU               Jan              300
     4        ICU               Feb               99
```

I already have a code (see below) that produces a plot with a x (admit type grouped my month) and y axes (median bed to dispo time), but I want to add a secondary Y axes which counts the number of patients which were used to compute each respective median.

For example, I want a secondary Y axis data point that corresponds to the month and admit type, so for Jan, the secondary Y axis data point will have a 2 separate counts 1)of the patients admitted to acute and 2) of the patients admitted to ICU.

```
 proc sgplot data=Combined;
 title "Median Bed Order To Dispo By Month, Admit Location"; 
 vbar MONTH_YEAR   / response=BED_ORDERED_TO_DISPO stat=median
 group = Admit_Type groupdisplay=cluster ;
 run;
```

I've been trying to adapt what I've found here but the plots my code produces are super messy and incorrect.

https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2019/01/14/align-y-y2-axes-sgplot.html

Desired output(pretend X's and *'s, respectively, are connected in a line graph corresponding to the Y axis):

```
     |        *                      |
  m  |   |    |              X   |   | #
  e  |   x    |              |   *   |
  d  |   |    |              |   |   |
     |-------------------------------|
      Acute ICU           Acute ICU  
        Jan                FEb
```

Code which I've tried that produce rubbish

```
proc sgplot data=Combined;
vbarbasic MONTH_YEAR/ response=Bed_Order_Hour y2axis; /*needs to be on y axis 1*/
group = Admit_Type
series x=MONTH_YEAR y=Pt_fin/ markers; *Pt_fin needs to be on y axis 2*/
run;
```

Comment: You haven't shown an example of wha tyou want or the code you've tried. The code above uses only one plot statement so you haven't tried to add anything yet. I would guess you would need to summarize your data first if you want to do this, so you may want to switch the vbarparm instead with text statements to show the values or an xaxistable depending on the layout you want, which you haven't show or indicated.

Comment: @Reeza See my updated post for what I want (visually) - I originality explained what I wanted textually. I'm aware what the first code produces and didn't include the second code as an attempt to not muddy up the waters with something that does not work.  Not sure why this question was marked down, I thought I explained the issue well - it just needed a little bit of further clarification.

Comment: Y2axis places it on the secondary axis, why are you using that when you note that you want it on axis1 and not using on the series statement. Your visual isn't clear. Is your second set of data just a x/y scatter type plot with the N or is the N another bar like your X?

Comment: I downvoted because you didn't show what you tried or what you want. For a graph, a word description isn't enough when you don't even specify if you want a bar chart with two bars or a bar and a point. You explain your calculations but not your visualization types at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your visualization explanation is weak.  You *might* want to use two plotting statements in your `SGPLOT`, `VBAR` and `VLINE`.

```
data have;
  do type = 'Acute', 'ICU';

    do month = '01jan2018'd to '31dec2018'd;

      do _n_ = 1 to floor (50 * ranuni(123));

        patid + 1;
        minutes = 10 + floor(1000 * ranuni(123));

        output;
      end;

      month = intnx ('month', month, 0, 'e');
    end;
  end;

  format month monname3.;
run;

ods html5 file="plot.html" path="c:\temp";

proc sgplot data=have;
  title "Median of patient minutes by month";
  vbar  month / group=type groupdisplay=cluster response=minutes stat=median;
  vline month / group=type groupdisplay=cluster response=minutes stat=freq y2axis ;
run;

ods html5 close;
```

[image]

The `vline` presents the viewer a secondary focus on the frequency for each median. The same information (as an aspect) of the median could be communicated instead with just a modification of the vbar intensity.  The highest freq bars (of median) would be 'strongest' shade and the lower 'freq' bars would be faded.

Comment: this is genius, thank you! Now I will teach myself how to fiddle around with axis labels and aesthetics!